# Visual Studio Continuous Integration Server Build error - Workspace Exception

Tags: visual-studio, continuous-integration, build-automation, tfsbuild

I've setup continuous integration on the build settings in Visual Studio for an ASP.NET MVC 4 project written in C#. We use TFS2012 on VisualStudio.com for our source control and have set all workspaces to server. Last week things were building fine but this morning this error started cropping up:

> 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)  Exception Message: Workspace
>   2_5_Main;Elastic Build (AwesomeInc) does not reside on this computer.  If
>   this computer was recently renamed, the workspace may be updated by
>   running 'tf workspaces /updateComputerName:oldComputerName'. (type
>   NotSupportedException) Exception Stack Trace:  Server stack trace:
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.RequireLocal()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.Get(GetRequest[]
>   requests, GetOptions options, GetFilterCallback filterCallback, Object
>   userData, String[] itemAttributeFilters, String[] itemPropertyFilters,
>   Boolean alwaysQueryConflicts, Conflict[]& conflicts)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.Get(GetRequest[]
>   requests, GetOptions options, GetFilterCallback filterCallback, Object
>   userData, String[] itemAttributeFilters)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.Get(GetRequest[]
>   requests, GetOptions options, GetFilterCallback filterCallback, Object
>   userData)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.Get(GetRequest
>   request, GetOptions options, GetFilterCallback filterCallback, Object
>   userData)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.Get(GetRequest
>   request, GetOptions options)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.TfGet.TfGetCore.RunCommand(VersionControlScope
>   versionControlScope, Workspace workspace, String getting, String
>   nonFatalError, String version, String fileSpec, GetOptions options,
>   RecursionType recursion)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, IMessageSink replySink)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message
>   reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed,
>   MessageData& msgData)    at System.Func`9.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.TfGet.TfGetCore.EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity`1.System.Activities.IAsyncCodeActivity.FinishExecution(AsyncCodeActivityContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityData.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)

Nobody has renamed any computers and if I understand this right, I think it refers to the server name?

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Why server workspaces?

Comment: Are your Workspaces set to Clean: None, Outputs or All? Are you using TFVC or Git?